# VBA error code 438 'object doesn't support this property or method' in if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to find a solution for this error for several hours and I can't make it work. The code worked before I aggregated the AND statements in the first if `And (final.Cells(j, 4) = rawSort(m, 2)) And (final.Cells(j, 6) = rawSort(m, 3))` and if i remove it it works but not with the desired result.

I don't know what to do, any help will be appreciated.

Here is the function (j is an index)

`Public Function waste%(j)
    Set final = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master file")
    Set rawSort = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input Volume")
    Dim index As Integer
    index = rawSort.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row`

```
    For m = 2 To index
        If (final.Cells(j, 2) = rawSort.Cells(m, 1) And (final.Cells(j, 4) = rawSort(m, 2)) And (final.Cells(j, 6) = rawSort(m, 3))) Then
             If (rawSort.Cells(m, 2) = "March" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2) = "June" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2) = "September" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2) = "December") And rawSort.Cells(m - 1, 1) = rawSort.Cells(m, 1) And rawSort.Cells(m - 2, 1) = rawSort.Cells(m, 2) And m > 3 Then
                final.Cells(j, 37) = final.Cells(j, 31) / (final.Cells(j, 31) + rawSort.Cells(m - 2, 10).Value + rawSort.Cells(m - 1, 10).Value + rawSort.Cells(m, 10).Value) 'local

            ElseIf rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "March" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "June" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "September" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "December" And rawSort.Cells(m - 1, 1).Value = rawSort.Cells(m, 1).Value And m > 2 Then
                final.Cells(j, 37) = final.Cells(j, 31) / (final.Cells(j, 31) + rawSort.Cells(m - 1, 10).Value + rawSort.Cells(m, 10).Value) 'local

            ElseIf rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "March" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "June" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "September" Or rawSort.Cells(m, 2).Value = "December" And m > 1 Then
                final.Cells(j, 37) = final.Cells(j, 31) / (final.Cells(j, 31) + rawSort.Cells(m, 10).Value)  'local
            Else
                final.Cells(j, 37) = "lel" 'error message, will be removed later
            End If
        Else
            final.Cells(j, 37) = Null


        End If
    Next m
```

`End Function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three components of your if statement are as follow:

```
Final.Cells(j, 2) = rawSort.Cells(m, 1)
Final.Cells(j, 4) = rawSort(m, 2)
Final.Cells(j, 6) = rawSort(m, 3)
```

Notice anything? You're missing '.cells' in the second two.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed it... all morning lost and a headache gained... Thanks a lot!! Now that it's finally working i can move to another aspect that I worked around but i yet don't understand why it didn't work. I had another if that was as follows "if x <> 0 And x <> Null" and even when I had values of x = 600 the condition was not met. I solved it by changing the And for an Or but i'd prefer having an And there. Got any ideas why this happened?